# A small piece of code which attract top_tracks from Last.fm API by pylast software

Tags: python, last.fm

I modified the code published on [smbrown.wordpress.com](http://smbrown.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/last-fm-python-wordle-fun-with-pylast/) which can extract the top tracks using the Last.fm API as below:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import time
 import pylast
 import re

 from md5 import md5


 user_name = '*******'
 user_password = '*******'
 password_hash = pylast.md5("*******")
 api_key = '***********************************'
 api_secret = '****************************'
 top_tracks_file = open('top_tracks_wordle.txt', 'w')
 network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = api_key, api_secret =  api_secret, username =                user_name, password_hash = password_hash)



 # to make the output more interesting for wordle viz.
 # run against all periods. if you just want one period,
 # delete the others from this list
 time_periods = ['PERIOD_12MONTHS', 'PERIOD_6MONTHS', 'PERIOD_3MONTHS', 'PERIOD_OVERALL']
 # time_periods = ['PERIOD_OVERALL']
 #####
 ## shouldn't have to edit anything below here
 #####
 md5_user_password = md5(user_password).hexdigest()

 sg = pylast.SessionKeyGenerator(network) #api_key, api_secret
 session_key = sg.get_session_key(user_name, md5_user_password)

 user = pylast.User(user_name, network) #api_key, api_secret, session_key

 top_tracks = []
 for time_period in time_periods:
     # by default pylast returns a seq in the format:
     #  "Item: Andrew Bird - Fake Palindromes, Weight: 33"
     tracks = user.get_top_tracks(period=time_period)

     # regex that tries to pull out only the track name (
     # for the ex. above "Fake Palindromes"
     p = re.compile('.*[\s]-[\s](.*), Weight: [\d]+')

     for track in tracks:
         m = p.match(str(track))
         **track = m.groups()[0]**                  <-----------Here---------------
         top_tracks.append(track)
     # be nice to last.fm's servers
     time.sleep(5)

 top_tracks = "\n".join(top_tracks)
 top_tracks_file.write(top_tracks)
 top_tracks_file.close()
```

When the script is run to the position where marked by " <-----------Here--------------", I got a error message :".... line 46, in

track = m.groups()[0]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'"

I just stuck here for over a day, and do not know what to do next. Can anyone give me some clue about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently some track names do not match your regex, so match() returns None. Catch the exception and examine `track`.